# python decorators, nested function

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to figure out why i need a one more nested function when using decorators. Here is an example:

```
 def func(f):
    def deco(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return deco

@func
def sum(a, b):
    return a+b

print sum(5, 10)
```

Code works, everything is fine. But why do i need to create nested "deco" function?
Let's try without it:

```
def func(f):
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

@func
def sum(a, b):
    return a+b

print sum(5, 10)
```

Code fails.

So there are three questions:

1. Why second sample does not works?
2. Why args,kwargs are "magically" appears if we are using a nested function?
3. What can i do, to make 2nd sample work? Except nesting another function, ofcourse.

Comment: A decorator should return a function not the result of a function. In your first example, it returns a function ... In the second, it returns whatever your function f returns.

Comment: And what about 2nd and 3rd questions?

Comment: `*args` and `**kwargs` do not appear "magically", the arguments will only be defined once you call your decorated function (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Comment: In short: Because the contract for decorators is that they are function factories: They take a function and return a new function. In your second example, your `func(f)` returns the *result of a function call*. But the decorator needs to return a *function* (that hasn't been called yet).

Comment: Note: @func is just some syntactic sugar for `sum = func(sum)`, `args` and `kwargs` only matter when you call this new definition of `sum`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Why second sample does not works?

   Because you are calling the function on the return, you are not returning a function.
2. Why args,kwargs are "magically" appears if we are using a nested function?

   They don't appear magically, we are declaring them, as in:

   ```
   def deco(*args, **kwargs):
   ```

   These are generic, and will match any function signature (argument list).  You don't have to call them `args` and `kwargs`, that's just a convention, you could call them `sharon` and `tracy`.
3. What can i do, to make 2nd sample work? Except nesting another function, ofcourse.

   Well you don't say what you expect the 2nd sample to do.  But I guess to turn it into a decorator then:

   ```
   def func(f):
       return f
   ```

   But that's not doing a lot!

By the way, it is usually a bad idea to override an existing Python builtin (`sum`) - you have to have a very good reason for that.